# Transormation of object

Tags: modeling

I have a reference and i want  to make it 
I made a flat design , now i want to transform in sphere shape[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **First, if possible, create a "minimum unit" of your pattern**. For example, given these 8 shapes:

   [image]

   you can join them together (select, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>), but then you also have to put the pieces that "leak" into the next unit square back into the repeating unit:

   [image]

   The complexity of this task really depends on your model!
2. Make sure your pattern is "laid flat" **onto the X-Y surface**: rotate it in the right way, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > "*Rotation & Scale*"

   [image]
3. Enable the **"*Tissue*" add-on**:

   > File > User Preferences > Add-ons > "Mesh: Tissue" > check
4. Create a **cube, set the subdivision surface modifier**, set the render divisions to 1, then "Apply".

   [image]
5. Select the pattern, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+select the subdivided cube, hit <kbd>Space</kbd> and search "**Tessellate**". Choose XY: adaptive, Z: proportional, and hit "ok". You may want to enable "smooth" shading on the resulting mesh.

   [image]

   **This will create a patterned mesh, made by repeating your patter on every face of the subdivided cube**. It works because the object is made of quadrilateral faces. it wouldn't work on a UV sphere or Icosphere.